# Encouraging a young boy to wear his yarmulke

Tags: children-parenting, kippa-yarmulka

I imagine this is a common issue.  Parents decide that it is time for their son to start wearing a yarmulke. He, being in the range of 2-4, doesn't recognize the value of having something on his head that falls off when he turns upside down.  What are some effective strategies for getting a young child to be willing, or perhaps even excited, to wear his yarmulke?

Comment: Skirts often have that same issue.

Comment: Maybe this is too simplistic YEZ but using kipot with bright colors, cartoon characters, sports teams, the child's name, etc., might encourage him to wear it.

Comment: @JJLL That seems valid.  (I don't not have an answer, I'm just fishing for other suggestions.)

Comment: Patience..........

Comment: This is a [parenting question](http://parenting.stackexchange.com) not a Judaism question...

Comment: RE "doesn't recognize the value" Yes, well, that's because the value of wearing one is ... Unclear, for lack of a better term.  Your son's concerns are rational and valid.

Comment: @Shmuel, [questions about "general knowledge (science, etc.) as it relates directly to Judaism" are on-topic](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1473).

Comment: Noted. I didn't vote to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about parenting.

Comment: @mevaqesh "about parenting" != "not about Judaism" in the same way that "about history" != "not about Judaism". Not sure why you think this case is particularly special.

Comment: You misunderstood. Nothing is special about parenting. Anything not about Judaism, isn't about Judaism. For an (unresolved) debate on which questions not about Judaism itself, are on topic here, see http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/262/8775.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to take him to the store to pick out his *very own* yarmulke. Now it is *his choice* and he is doing it because *he wants to do it*. And every day he wears it he is wearing *his* yarmulke that *he* picked out.

I have found that it is always best to give children choices when the choices are limited to approved behaviors. Children thus feel empowered and no longer feel that they are simply taking orders from a parent but are making the decision themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is as big of a problem as you would think. If his father always wears a yarmulke, that alone could excite him: "You get to wear a yarmulke just like daddy does!".

With regards to it falling off, you could always add clips.

Just like with regards to everything in child-rearing, if the kid grows up in an atmosphere that honors Torah and Halachah, he is more likely to honor and respect the Torah and Halachah on his own. He is then more likely to return the yarmulke to his head on his own if it falls off.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I didn't think it is a "big" problem - I just see it being something to consider.  Personally, my son will yell that he wants cavities and denounces all future rights to anything with sugar in it _because_ we want him to brush his teeth.  And not all kids have hair long enough for clips.

Comment: Re "With regards to it falling off, you could always add clips": thumb tacks work great.

Comment: @msh210 thumb tacks work great for people who are bald. But, as funny as that is, I don't recommend you suggest this to your rebbe. Nor should you suggest that he transplant some of his beard hair to his head to make it easier to wear a kippah.